# Is there any limit on page subscribed by a Facebook messenger app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-messenger-bot

I am trying to develop a Facebook messenger app and subscribe multiple Facebook pages on it because I don't want to create multiple Facebook apps which need to go through the Facebook review process each.

So, I tried out subscribing multiple page on it and it seems working. But, I think is there any limit of subscribed Facebook pages on any Facebook messenger app.

Comment: Not sure if there’s an actual limit, but I even if there was I doubt you would reach it anytime soon. Using one app to subscribe for updates from multiple pages is common practice.

Comment: So, Is it the same approach Motion.ai and other such platforms are doing?
@CBroe

Comment: Yes, more or less.

Comment: So did you find an answer? I am also in a similar situation.

Comment: Not yet but didn't have any issues on subscribing 10 Facebook pages.